# Errors from ifconfig?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ifconfig

In my Redhat 7 Linux machine I see - `RX errors 413556` and after some time I see the same error value - 413556 ( not increasing ).

First question - is it possible to know when this error triggered?

In case value is not increasing, can we say that network is healthy for now?

```
eop1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 104.19.8.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 104.19.8.255
        ether 12:7a:1a:60:2e:e9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4064026662  bytes 2422841475170 (2.2 TiB)
        RX errors 413556  dropped 49020  overruns 1537  frame 412019
        TX packets 3341156925  bytes 3692324143458 (3.3 TiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 90  memory 0x96000000-967fffff
```

Comment: If errors are not growing you are fine. Still worth finding a root cause. It could be someone tripped over a cable, or a brownout.

Comment: Without you telling us the update of the machine, the number of errors is irrelevant.

Comment: number is static ( the same number )

Comment: Problem with the ethernet cable. Indicates a problem with the physical/electrical medium (Layer 1). The number starts at 0 upon reboot. Replace the cable/reseat it if the number of errors continues to grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This number is simply a count of the number of errors that have occurred since the network interface was brought into the 'up' state. It's mostly useful for monitoring trends. Since it's not increasing, you can assume that the network was experiencing problems previously, but is currently working fine.

To further debug the state of the interface, you might want to try putting some traffic on it, such as downloading a large file using the `curl` or `wget` command, and polling the interface using the `ifconfig` command to see if the number stays still, or starts increasing. If you see it increasing, then there's something wrong with either the physical network card, or the driver software that's allowing it to operate through the OS.

Here's a handy command to try downloading a relatively small file. This command will dump the output to `/dev/null` so there isn't any residual file to delete once you're done with your debugging effort.

```
$ wget -O /dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test10.zip
```

#### References

- [How to Test Your Internet Speed with a Terminal Command](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-test-your-internet-speed-with-a-terminal-command-1364123567)